# Monotonicity in $x$ of $\frac{x^\alpha - 1}{x-1}$

Tags: calculus, analysis, inequality

I'm trying to show that for fixed $\alpha$, the function $f(x)=\frac{x^\alpha-1}{x-1}$ is monotonic for $x>0$ -- either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing, depending on the choice of $\alpha$.  (Strictly speaking, it could also be constant if $\alpha\in\{0,1\}$.)

The input $x$ might be $1$, in which case we extend $f$ to be continuous there; in this case that means $f(1)=\alpha$.

It appears that when $\alpha>1$ or $\alpha<0$ that $f$ is strictly increasing, and that when $0<\alpha<1$ it is strictly decreasing.  But I cannot figure out how to prove this.  Of course when $\alpha$ is a natural number it is clear since then $f(x)$ is a polynomial with nonnegative coefficients.  And if $\alpha$ is a negative integer a similar argument can be used.  Furthermore there are other special values of $\alpha$ for which it is clear (e.g. $\alpha=1/2$).

But this sort of argument is limited to, at best, the case when $\alpha$ is rational, so it doesn't seem particularly helpful for establishing it in general.  I suppose some sort of limiting argument could possibly be made based on this, but it seems more likely that there's an easier, probably differentiation-based way that I'm missing.

Thank you!

Comment: Differentiate. ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: First thing I tried.  I assume a solution will probably involve differentation, but a simple "differentiate, check positivity" didn't seem to go anywhere.  I might just be missing why the derivative is positive (or negative for $0<\alpha<1$).

Comment: I have not written out a solution for all cases. But take for example $\alpha\gt 1$. When you differentiate, the bottom is safely positive, the top is $(\alpha-1)x^\alpha -\alpha x^{\alpha-1}+1$. This is $0$ at $x=1$. Its derivative is positive for $x\gt 1$, so it is positive for $x\gt 1$.

Comment: Hm, somehow I failed to notice that last time, thanks.  I'll try going through this a second time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I feel a bit silly; André Nicolas is right, it's just a bit of differentiation that I messed up earlier.  Here's a full solution.

The derivative $f'(x)$ is $\frac{\alpha x^{\alpha-1}(x-1) - (x^\alpha-1)}{(x-1)^2}$; we want to show this is positive (negative).  It suffices to consider $x\ne 1$, because the fact that $f(x)$ has a limit at $1$ shows that if $f$ is increasing (respectively, decreasing) on each side of $1$, then it must be increasing (respectively, decreasing) overall.  Hence it suffices to show the numerator (call it $g(x)$) is positive (respectively, negative).

The numerator $g(x)$ is equal to $(\alpha-1)x^\alpha - \alpha x^{\alpha-1} + 1$.  Then $g'(x)=\alpha(\alpha-1)x^{\alpha-2}(x-1)$.  Hence if $\alpha>1$ or $\alpha<0$, $g'(x)$ has the same sign as $x-1$, and so $x=1$ is the unique global minimum of $g(x)$, and if $0<\alpha<1$, it has opposite sign, so $x=1$ is the unique global maximum of $g(x)$.  But either way, $g(1)=0$; and so either way, for $x\ne 1$, we conclude that $g(x)$ has the appropriate sign, and hence so does $f'(x)$.